# How do I play Secops (custom scenarios) in CO-OP over LAN?

Tags: arma-armed-assault

I'm fairly new to ARMA but I've created a mission in the single player scenario tab using the mission wizard. I then copied that mission file to the multiplayer mission folder however when I play it with my friend over LAN one of us spawns on the ground alive while the rest of us fall from the helicopter to our instant deaths.

Basically I just want to be able to play Secops over LAN with my friend.

Comment: Just to be clear: Secops means custom scenarios?

Comment: Yeah (stands for secondary operations) basically you spawn and then HQ give you random tasks and enemies and things randomly spawn rather than a set mission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found a solution to my problem although its more of a hacky work around, however at least it works...

Basically host the LAN Secops game as you would usually but only with the host in game, the AI will then take up the other slots. Once in game the helicopter will land safely with AI and host, then invite the other players to join who will take on either empty slots or an AI player.

Voila! - You'll then all be in game and in the same squad.

***Steps:***

1. Host LAN Secops game with only the host and AI.
2. Wait for the helicopter to land safely.
3. Invite other players to take over AI and empty slots.
4. Enjoy Secops over multiplayer!

*Like I said this method isn't exactly perfect but it gets the job done. If anyone else has any other methods or indeed better ones then please don't hesitate to give your answer!*